# How to scroll elements inside div horizontally javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

**Description**

I have a div with several elements inside which are in sum longer than the div itself.
See the following snippet for better understanding:

**Code**

```css
.boxSlider {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: cyan;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxSlider">
  <div class="box">Box 1</div>
  <div class="box">Box 2</div>
  <div class="box">Box 3</div>
  <div class="box">Box 4</div>
  <div class="box">Box 5</div>
  <div class="box">Box 6</div>
  <div class="box">Box 7</div>
  <div class="box">Box 8</div>
  <div class="box">Box 9</div>
  <div class="box">Box 10</div>
</div>

<input type="Button" value="Scroll left"/>
<input type="Button" value="Scroll right" />
```

**Expected output**

I want to use the buttons to scroll left or right using jquery or plain javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *[element.scroll(...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scroll)* in order to accomplish what you want:

Some notes:

1. Be aware [browser compatilibity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scroll#browser_compatibility).
2. You could simply used [`element.left += 50`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft) but you lose the smooth feature which, in my opinion, is more user-friendly. In other hand, is [compatible with all browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft#browser_compatibility).

```js
const boxSlider = document.getElementById('boxSlider');

document.getElementById("btnLeft").onclick = () => {
  boxSlider.scroll({
         left: boxSlider.scrollLeft + 100,
         behavior: 'smooth'
  });
}
     
document.getElementById("btnRight").onclick = () => {
  boxSlider.scroll({
         left: boxSlider.scrollLeft - 100,
         behavior: 'smooth'
  });
}
```

```css
.boxSlider {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: cyan;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="boxSlider" class="boxSlider">
  <div class="box">Box 1</div>
  <div class="box">Box 2</div>
  <div class="box">Box 3</div>
  <div class="box">Box 4</div>
  <div class="box">Box 5</div>
  <div class="box">Box 6</div>
  <div class="box">Box 7</div>
  <div class="box">Box 8</div>
  <div class="box">Box 9</div>
  <div class="box">Box 10</div>
</div>

<input id="btnLeft" type="Button" value="Scroll left"/>
<input id="btnRight" type="Button" value="Scroll right" />
```

Comment: How do you make a left += 50px?

Comment: @PhilipFlörl I updated the answer so you can check this thing you working